# Python 2.7.6, KeyError: 'data' when trying to run script

Tags: python, facebook, github, keyerror

First of all, I am totally new at python. I am a graphic designer and I need to get group members photos for a group logo. I have found this:
https://github.com/lionaneesh/IIITD-Students-Collage
and it pretty much should do the thing I need, but apparently I am doing something wrong and it does not work as intended.

When I execute this script:

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen


fp = open("test2.txt")
data = json.loads(fp.read())
fp.close()

user_photos = {} # id -> [User's Name, Photo URL]

for user in data["data"]:
    print user
    page = urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/" + user["id"] + "?fields=picture")
    page_data = json.loads(page.read())
    photo_url = page_data["picture"]["data"]["url"]
    user_photos[user["id"]] = [user["name"], photo_url]

fp = open("user_photos.json", "w")
fp.write(json.dumps(user_photos))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for user in data["data"]:
KeyError: 'data'
>>>
```

Could someone explain to me how to fix it or where to seek for help?

edit: this is how the data in text2.txt looks:

```
{
  "id": "1390694364479028", 
  "members": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Patryk Wiśniewski", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "321297624692717"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Backed PL", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "1440205746235525"
      },
```

and so on, with other group members infos

Comment: I would print data to see exactly what is in there.

Comment: I added the exact structure needed in my answer. Your structure does not match it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you should have exactly the same structure as the following in your txt file bar the details.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Arushi Jain", 
      "administrator": false, 
      "id": "100000582289046"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Ajay Yadav", 
      "administrator": false, 
      "id": "100004213058283"
    }, 
    and so on ........

  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/114462201948585/members?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=712305377"
  }
}
```

{

```
 {
  "data": [                    # how yours should look
   {
        "name": "Patryk Wiśniewski",
        "administrator": false,
        "id": "321297624692717"
      },
      {
        "name": "Patryk Kurowski",
        "administrator": false,
        "id": "1429534777317507"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jan Konieczny",
        "administrator": false,
        "id": "852450774783365"
      }

  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/114462201948585/members?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=712305377"
  }
}
```

That is the very first thing that is executed in the loop so if it does not match exactly then it will fail as it does in your error.

Comment: I have edited my post and provided first 2 entries from test2.txt, as Veedrac asked for it too.

Comment: I have actually tried deleting the first line ( "  "id": "1390694364479028", 
  "members": { " ), but it ended up screaming that it's not a proper JSON file.

Comment: open the example .txt file and copy the structure exactly.

Comment: I've made new txt file just to test it - now it gives different error. I've copied the example and error onto [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/s2MqyDz7).

Comment: @suckinsyn_van, I have run the get_photo_links.py using the json in my answer and it works fine.

Comment: It does work for me too (using the example file), although I want to use my own. It does not want to read it apparently. Any ideas why? It's the same as the example one..

Comment: I used the exact details in your pastebin post in what I put in my updated answer. That code runs so after that I don't know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Neither I do not know what I am doing wrong, as I have just put THE SAME txt as I've used before and it.. works. I guess it was some kind of "morning without coffee" problem. Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyError` means that there is no such key in a dict object. Therefore it means your file does not contain JSON data structure like this according to your script.

```
{"data": {"id": 10000}, {"id": 20000}, {"id": 30000}}
```

It would help if you posted the contents of `test2.txt` or the output of `print(data)`.

Edit: according to your text2.txt file, your program flow should be like this

```
for user in data["members"]["data"]:
    print user
    page = urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/" + user["id"] + "?fields=picture")
    page_data = json.loads(page.read())
    photo_url = page_data["picture"]["data"]["url"]
    user_photos[user["id"]] = [user["name"], photo_url]
```

You just simply change `data["data"]` to `data["members"]["data"]` to make your script work.

Comment: I have edited my post and provided first 2 entries from test2.txt.

Comment: I probably have made some kind of mistake in the txt file itself, case closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just don't have a JSON field for "data" in test2.txt